# Do extra brackets matter in formulas?

Tags: formula, validation-rule, trailhead

I am creating a Validation  rule. Trailhead states that I should use following formula:

`ISPICKVAL( StageName , "Closed Won") && ( Delivery_Schedule_Date__c - CloseDate ) > 14`

I have the following with an extra bracket before the 2nd AND condition:

`ISPICKVAL( StageName , "Closed Won") && **(**( Delivery_Schedule_Date__c - CloseDate ) > 14 **)**`

No Error is found in the formula when I use the "check syntax" button,
but it doesn't let me complete trailhead.

Can you please tell if the extra bracket matters?

Comment: It should not matter until an unless extra parenthesis changes the result based on their placement. Which trailhead are you trying to solve?

Comment: Not sure how Trailhead verifies what you enter: might be fairly literal matching give or take whitespace. So although functionally equivalent, it may not accept extra tokens like brackets in expressions.

Comment: @Rohit :Trailhead is Improve Data Quality for Your Sales and Support Teams

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, extra parentheses are not a problem regarding formula fields. In fact, the parentheses used in the trailhead module are extraneous as well:

```
ISPICKVAL(StageName , "Closed Won") && Delivery_Schedule_Date__c - CloseDate > 14
```

The trailhead system typically runs a DML operation and verifies that a certain error occurred. However, if you've reused your org for other projects, those validation rules, etc may be interfering with the trailhead module. Try removing any other customizations (validation rules, processes, required custom fields, etc), and try again.

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox , i have tried on a new  org  & it did worked